# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" got message when I try to mocha

Tags: node.js, vue.js, jestjs, mocha.js

I was using jest now on vue/nuxt.
And I am trying to change TDD by mocha and chai.
Installed mocha though  `npm i mocha --save-dev`

package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "mocha"
},
```

test/list.spec.json

```
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('test', function () {
  it('should be rendered', function () {
    const comp = [1, 2, 3];
    expect(Math.max(...comp)).to.above(1);
  });
});
```

Error message when I typed `npm test`

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

What is problem with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the import syntax in a Node app (`import { expect } from 'chai';`) if your project isn't properly configured to use this newer syntax. The original Node syntax pre JS modules is `const variable = require('./folder/file')`

You have to set up Jest or the project you work on to work with ES6 Modules. In package.json, add `"type": "module"`. Here's an explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/